# How to get size of data available thru stdin with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, stdin

If I get a handle to `stdin` from a console app like so:

```
HANDLE hStdIn = ::GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

I can then read data from it:

```
BYTE buff[32];
DWORD dwcbRead = 0;
BOOL bReadRes = ::ReadFile(hStdIn, buff, SIZEOF(buff), &dwcbRead, NULL);
```

My question is, how do I know how many bytes are available before I read them?

PS. `ReadFile` seems to block if there's no data available to read.

Comment: Not fully duplicate question.  The referred link (another question) only solves partial question, when stdin is redirected.  Anton Kovalenko's answer shows us that `PeekConsoleInput` can be used for console stdin.  We should combine the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReadConsoleInput` to read raw input events and `PeekConsoleInput` to examine them without removing from the input queue. There is a bunch of caveats here:

1. Your standard input might be redirected, then you'll have to determine its type and act accordingly. If it's a file, it won't block and you just go ahead and read. If it's a pipe, `PeekNamedPipe` provides some help.
2. There is no one-to-one correspondence between input events and characters.
3. If `ENABLE_LINE_MODE` is set on the console, `ReadFile`/`ReadConsole` would block if there is no newline yet entered; additionally, line editing facilities are unavailable before you actually *call* `ReadConsole`, and when you call `ReadConsole`, it will block.

I would recommend doing `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` (or trying the latter with fallback to the former) in a separate thread. Your main thread may do something useful and eventually check (or wait for) readyness of the reading thread.

Answer (score 1):

[Checking the availability of input on stdin](http://www.jetdrone.com/post/1/16)

Comment: Haha. I saw `PeekNamedPipe` myself but because of its name I thought, "No way it'd work." But what would you know. It does seem to work. Although for some weird reason if there's no input it returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` is set to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`... hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

For console input, you don't know how may characters a user or machine will deliver.
For example, my program asks you to type in a sentence.  Which sentence are you thinking of?  Which one will you type?  How many letters in the sentence?

If you really want to know, I highly recommend a course in reading minds or in the case of the input from a non-human, a course in predicting the future.

For a file, you can check on the size.

Comment: I see your point. But, you're not correct. Supposedly `PeekNamedPipe` can provide you that info according to the post by Remy Lebeau.

Comment: @ahmd0: Which platform?  Is `PeekNamedPipe` part of the standard C++ language?  Also, how does PeekNamedPipe know how many characters I intend to type?  Not even I know that!

Comment: I think `PeekNamedPipe` comes with the new Microsoft MRT... (Mind Reading Technology.) So it does know what you will type, even before you do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, and yes, it will sit there waiting for your input to fill the buffer. If that's not what you want, then don't use ReadFile.

There are other functions that are meant for reading console I/O, including ones that give you the number of pending "events".

[Console IO functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)